# Cannot do DragDrop in a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

Iam trying to make a method where an image from one picturebox can drag and drop into another picturebox with some kind of effects. Whenever i try to code DragDrop into picturebox i got this error.[image]

Comment: Is that a standard Windows Forms PictureBox Control? What is the .Net Framework version in use?

Comment: Yes Windows forms. .NET 4.8 VS2019

Comment: I got the solution actually, It consider DragEventArgs as System.Windows.DragEventArgs and when i just changed it to System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs it works fine..hehehe Thanks alot for your attension

Comment: So, you're referencing PresentationFramework assemblies in your WinForms project. I suggest you put all code that needs WPF stuff in separate class files, so you don't mix objects that have identical names in both assemblies (as Point, Color etc.) but are not compatible. Otherwise you're constantly struggling with this kind of *ambiguity*.